# Powerbuilder: what to code in the pfc_retrieve() event when using FILTER style linkage

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

I have two master-detail datawindow which are linked through pfc's linkage service. Now I have read in the documentation that when using FILTER style retrieval code must be placed inside the detail window's `pfc_retrieve` event.

What code/function call should I place there so that when the master windows's retrieval has been finished, the detail window's data are also retrieved?

Comment: Would someone with at least 1500 rep please create a powerbuilder-pfc tag?

Comment: @Colin: Many thanks. There's a number of questions that should have this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the detail DataWindow is displaying. You want to populate the detail with whatever data goes with the master. If the detail contains the definition of terms, you might retrieve the entire table of term definitions. If the detail depends on the retrieval arguments of the master, the detail will need to use some or all of them in the 
select, and you would pass them when you retrieve it in pfc_retrieve.